# Assign rects to specific images in a list using pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm a novice programmer and I'm currently trying to create an animation cycle for a sprite in a game I'm working on. However, due to how the game works, I want the program to assign a rect to each frame using a variable called 'pos' to determine the coordinates. So I want the program to go to a specific image in a list and assign it a rect before displaying it. However, I'm struggling with the syntax. Here's my code (let me know if you need more of it for context):

```
class Customer(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, group, layer, pos):
            super(Customer, self).__init__()
            #adding all the images to sprite array
            self.images = []
            self.images.append(pygame.image.load("customerplaceholder.png"))
            self.images.append(pygame.image.load("customerplaceholder2.png"))
            #index value determines which image from the array is displayed 
            self.index = 0
            for self.index in self.images:
                self.rect = self.images[self.index].get_rect(center = pos)
            self._layer = layer
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, group)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [`pygame.srite.sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) is meant only represent one object in the scene. The class `Customer` should have only one attribute `rect` and one attribute `image`. However you have to create 2 [Instance Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects) of this. e.g.:

```py
class Customer(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, group, layer, pos, imagefile):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, group)
        self.image = pygame.image.load(imagefile)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = pos)
        self._layer = layer
```

```py
c1 = Customer(group, layer, pos1, "customerplaceholder.png")
c2 = Customer(group, layer, pos2, "customerplaceholder2.png")
```

Note that the list should not be in the `Customer` class, but you can create a list of `customers`:

```py
customers = []
customers.append(Customer(group, layer, pos1, "customerplaceholder.png"))
customers.append(Customer(group, layer, pos2, "customerplaceholder2.png"))
```